# python: isinstance(value, Sequence[Real])

Tags: python, type-hinting, abc

Python's `typing` module allows containers of specific object types to be described, such as `Sequence[numbers.Real]`. However, the container interfaces in `collections.abc` do not accept such parameters, so I can only check `isinstance(value, abc.Sequence)`. Is there any directway to check if `isinstance(value, Sequence[numbers.Real])` (without using loops/comprehensions etc)

Comment: The type hinting is aimed at specialist type-checking tools such as `mypy`, not at run-time checking. As such, `isinstance()` is not really supported for generic types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, if a need my code to behave differently for a list of `X`s than for a list of `Y`s, what would be the suggested way of doing that? Do I have to use `all(isinstance(val, X) for val in seq)` or something like that, or is there some better way of doing it??

Comment: Try not to write code that needs to check for types in the first place?

Comment: See if https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard can help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: despite the python mottos, not always possible. even the standard libraries themselves make heavy use of `isinstance` is some cases.

Comment: don't try and enforce things (e.g all list elements *must* be of `X` type). Just accept the list and raise an appropriate error if the type doesn't match.